# Align deleting lines

Tags: align

This might be a really simple problem, but the class I'm in gave us a writing assignment with zero introduction or instruction on how to actually use LaTeX. Simply "google how to do it," so have patience with my inexperience, please.

I'm trying to align my equations (the one I'm doing now consists of three lines), but no matter if I use /align or {align} or {align*} I either cut off everything past 1 line, or all of my lines get cut off. I assume this is because of a syntax error, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
\begin{align}
$2(m+1)+1$ = $2m + 2 + 1$\nonumber\\
$2m + 2 + 1 \le 2^m$\nonumber\\
$2^m + 2 \le 2^m + 2^m = 2^{(m+1)}$\nonumber
\end{align}
```

Comment: Delete all the dollar signs. The `align` environment has already switched you into math mode.

Comment: You should also consider using `align*` instead, if I understand the purpose of `\nonumber` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at your `.log` file? This should be raising an error.

In LaTeX, there are two modes: textmode, for text, and mathmode, for math. However, when you switch you have to match how you do it: if you switch into mathmode with `\begin{align}`, your next switching command has to be `\end{align}`. Using `$` produces an error, and once LaTeX is confused it tries its best to salvage the error-free lines, so it skips some of your code.

Finally, it's worth remarking that: (1) `align*` is the same as `align`, but it doesn't number the equations, so it'll save you some writing. (2) If you want to use `align`'s functionality, of vertically aligning your text at a given point, place an `&` where you want the text to align (typically at the `=` and `\le` signs). If you don't want alignment, you can use the `gather` or `gather*` environments instead.

```
\begin{align*}
2(m+1)+1 &= 2m + 2 + 1\\
2m + 2 + 1 &\le 2^m\\
2^m + 2 &\le 2^m + 2^m = 2^{(m+1)}
\end{align*}
```

In general, if something seriously strange is going on, looking at the log file doesn't hurt.